# Rails nested_form for a recursive model association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

It's based on two models: Formula and Operand. A formula can have many Operands. Each operand can have many or none operands.

I've established a polymorphic association in which Operand belongs to operation and also have many operands as operator. Formula have many operands as operation itself.

I'm trying to build a nested_form that can handle this, but i'm stuck. I'm using simple_nested_form. Any help would be appreciated.

```
class Formula < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name, :client_id
  belongs_to :client

  has_many :operands, as: :operation, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :operands, allow_destroy: true

end

class Operand < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :operator
  belongs_to :operation, polymorphic: true

  has_many :operands, as: :operation, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :operands, allow_destroy: true

  OPERATOR_TYPES = ["+", "-", "*", "/"]
end
```

**UPDATE**

Based in models above, I add in formulas_controller:

```
  def new 
    @formula.operands.build 
  end
```

In the formula _form, I add fields_for :operands

```
= simple_nested_form_for @formula, :html => { :class => 'form-vertical' } do |f|
  = f.error_notification

  .form-inputs
    .row
      .span3= f.input :name
    .well  
      = f.fields_for :operands
      = f.link_to_add t('helpers.links.add'), :operands
```

And then, the partial _operands_fields, also rendering fields_for :operands

```
.well
  .row
    .span2= f.input :operator, collection: Operand::OPERATOR_TYPES
    .span3= f.input :numeric_operand
    .span3= f.link_to_remove t('helpers.links.remove')
  .well  
    = f.fields_for :operands
    = f.link_to_add t('helpers.links.add'), :operands
```

I think this should work, but it seems that when the formula form is rendered, it includes the fields_for the formula operand. Then, inside this partial, instead of including "Add", it renders another operand fields, and so on, ending in an infinite loop such this:

```
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Client Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "clients".* FROM "clients"  WHERE "clients"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered formulas/_operand_fields.html.haml (48.4ms)
  Rendered formulas/_operand_fields.html.haml (9.0ms)
  Rendered formulas/_operand_fields.html.haml (7.5ms)
  Rendered formulas/_operand_fields.html.haml (9.1ms)
  Rendered formulas/_operand_fields.html.haml (8.8ms)
  Rendered formulas/_operand_fields.html.haml (9.2ms)
  Rendered formulas/_operand_fields.html.haml (9.3ms)
  Rendered formulas/_operand_fields.html.haml (9.5ms)
  Rendered formulas/_operand_fields.html.haml (17.7ms)
  Rendered formulas/_operand_fields.html.haml (52.4ms)
  Rendered formulas/_operand_fields.html.haml (10.4ms)
  Rendered formulas/_operand_fields.html.haml (11.3ms)
```

Any ideas in how to solve this problem?